# How to save a shared data model and singleton manager?

Tags: android, android-activity, persistence

I have created a small singleton manager to store some data that are shared between 2 fragments.
How would I somehow save these data in case of crash? I understand that there are constructs like eventbus but this is for the purpose of practicing in android (I am newbie).
Using the approach of shared data model and singleton manager is there a way to ensure that the data are not lost on crash/memory reclaim etc?

Comment: Depends on the size of the data and the frequency of updates. You can write the data to a file, store it in shared preferences or write it to an SQLite database. All are pretty easy to do.

Comment: @DavidWasser:But aren't shared preferences for preferences?

Comment: No., Shared Preferences is a place where you can store bits of data persistently. You can store whatever you want there, however it becomes more complicated if you want to store complex objects. Shared Preferences is generally used to store simple data types only.

Comment: @DavidWasser:I need a custom object (implements Parcelable) to store (actually a list of those) and it seems to me that saving to a file is the most straightforward approach. What should I read about this? How to save to a file?

Comment: Here's an example of how to do it use `Serializable`.: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html  You can also serialize/deserialize it yourself (by hand).